# New line after subsubsection with llncs class

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, titlesec, lncs

I get a new line after each `chapter`, `section`, and `subsection`, but not after anything lower than `subsection`, e.g. `subsubsection` or `paragraph`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\section{FooBar}
\dots
\subsection{BarFoo}
\dots
\subsubsection{Chakka}
\dots
\paragraph{Chu}
\dots

\end{document}
```

Do I have to use the `titlesec` package with the `titleformat` command or is there any other way?

(Off-topic: Is there a built-in function to include part of the compiled version as an image?)

Comment: I believe it's a conscious decision made by Springer. If you use the class for a submission, you shouldn't modify the appearance.

Comment: @egreg I guess so. However, lets just assume I would want to change it. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how the class defines the sectional units:

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                       {-18\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {12\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}%
                       {\normalfont\large\bfseries\boldmath
                        \rightskip=\z@ \@plus 8em\pretolerance=10000 }}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                       {-18\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {8\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath
                        \rightskip=\z@ \@plus 8em\pretolerance=10000 }}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                       {-18\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {-0.5em \@plus -0.22em \@minus -0.1em}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                       {-12\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {-0.5em \@plus -0.22em \@minus -0.1em}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
```

As you see, the fifth argument to `\@startsection` is negative for `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph`. Just make it positive. For instance:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                       {-18\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {4\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath
                        \rightskip=\z@ \@plus 8em\pretolerance=10000 }}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                       {-12\p@ \@plus -4\p@ \@minus -4\p@}%
                       {2\p@ \@plus 1\p@ \@minus 1\p@}%
                       {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape
                        \rightskip=\z@ \@plus 8em\pretolerance=10000 }}
\makeatother
```

Negative values in that argument tell LaTeX to use a "runin" style.